# Why would system calls (CreateProcess, stat & fopen) say a file doesn't exist, when it does?

Tags: windows

I have a C program that I've just noticed has some issues with some files/paths...
Not sure when this stopped working, but my guess is since Windows-7...

I can use CreateProcess(), fstat() and fopen() to access a file (in this particular case I'm using C:\windows\system32\soundrecorder.exe) and while the file does exist and I'm able to execute it using explorer or CMD.exe shell, accessing it with any of those other system calls returns an error that implies that the file doesn't exist.

My guess is that this is some kind of permissions issue with the 'C' program; however if that was the case, wouldn't I see the same issue when trying to run it via explorer or CMD.exe?

Comment: 64 bits windows and a 32 bits program? Muti-lingual Windows version?

Comment: 32-bit processes are redirected to c:\windows\syswow64.  Use c:\windows\sysnative\soundrecorder.exe when you want to start the 64-bit version.  Or build the 64-bit version of your program.

Comment: Right click on program and `Run As Administrator`. Also test on a file not located in `system32` directory.

Comment: @Aaron... didn't seem to matter

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments.

Comment: Observation: in the code I also tried c:\windows\syswow64\soundrecorder.exe and that did not work.  When I use explorer I see C:\windows\system32 as well as C:\windows\syswow64; but neither of those paths worked from my program.  And by the way, explorer does NOT show C:\windows\sysnative.

Comment: @Ed., `System32` gets redirected to `SysWOW64` for a 32-bit application. To allow access to the real `System32`, the WOW64 system also provides a *virtual* `Sysnative` directory. You won't see this directory in a 64-bit program such as Explorer. The situation here is that `soundrecorder.exe` is not built as a 32-bit application, so it's not to be found in `SysWOW64`. It's only built as a 64-bit application that's to be found in the real `System32` directory, which for a 32-bit application gets accessed via the virtual `Sysnative` directory.